# Navigating to another component which is not in hierarchy passing a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Am looking at navigating from `App.js`(which is the default component) to a new component which is not with in the hierarchy passing a function. Any input how can I do it?

I have a component `Question` which is used to display questions, also I have `Upvote` and `Downvote` component which takes care of upvoting and downvoting respectively.

Here is the code I have in place ..

```
import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import questions from '../questions';
import './../App.css';
import base from '../base';
import AddQuestionForm from './AddQuestionForm';
import AddQuestionButton from '../AddQuestionButton';
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    questions: {}
  };
  handleUpvote = key => {
    const questions = { ...this.state.questions };
    const updateQuestion = questions[key];
    updateQuestion.upvotes++;
    questions[key] = updateQuestion;
    this.setState({ questions });
  };
  handleDownvote = key => {
    const questions = { ...this.state.questions };
    const updateQuestion = questions[key];
    updateQuestion.downvotes++;
    questions[key] = updateQuestion;
    this.setState({ questions });
  };
  addQuestion = question => {
    const questions = { ...this.state.questions };
    questions[`question${Date.now()}`] = question;
    this.setState({ questions });
  };
//this is where I want to send the user to /question along with the function addQuestion, since thats the function used to insert a question.
  handleAddQuestionNavigation = () => {
    // this.props.addQuestion(this.addQuestion);
    this.props.history.push(`/question`);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref = base.syncState(`questions`, {
      context: this,
      state: 'questions'
    });
    // this.setState({ questions: questions })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* <AddQuestionForm
          history={this.props.history}
          addQuestion={this.addQuestion}
        /> */}
        {/* <AddQuestionButton
          history={this.props.history}
          addQuestion={this.addQuestion}
        /> */}
        <button onClick={this.handleAddQuestionNavigation}>
          Add Question
        </button>
        {Object.keys(this.state.questions).map(key => (
          <Question
            key={key}
            index={key}
            details={this.state.questions[key]}
            handleUpvote={this.handleUpvote}
            handleDownvote={this.handleDownvote}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import AddQuestionForm from './AddQuestionForm';
import ShowQuestion from './ShowQuestion';
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/question" component={AddQuestionForm} />
      <Route path="/questions/:qId" component={ShowQuestion} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
export default Router;
```

This is AddQuestionForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
class AddQuestionForm extends React.Component {
    titleRef = React.createRef();
    descRef = React.createRef();
    createQuestion = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const q = {
            title: this.titleRef.current.value,
            desc: this.descRef.current.value,
            upvotes: 0,
            dedownvotessc: 0
        };
        this.addQuestion(q);
        this.props.history.push(`/questions/question${Date.now()}`);
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.createQuestion}>
                <input
                    name="title"
                    ref={this.titleRef}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Submit your question"
                />
                <textarea
                    name="desc"
                    ref={this.descRef}
                    placeholder="say something about your question"
                />
                <button type="submit">Add Question</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default AddQuestionForm;
```

Any inputs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating in react-router-dom should be with the Link/NavLink Components,
to is the path that matches the route

Becuase you want to send a function to /question path.
you could also write Link Component as 
Where Link accpets an object containing the pathname, and state which u can access
inside the question component

Comment: for some reason it didn't save the code i wrote
*<Link to='/question >Navigate To Questions</Link>*
*<Link to={{pathanme: '/questions', state: {addQuestion: this.addQuestion}}> Navigate To Questions and pass a function to it</Link>*

Comment: I checked this, the bottleneck I see here is how do I pass a function(which changes the state of a variable) to the destination component.